# HTML doesn't load webpack-built files

Tags: html, reactjs, production, webpack, webpack-dev-server

My build on webpack-dev-server works fine, but when I compile with `NODE_ENV=production webpack --config` html file outputs blank page.

In dev-server html I load files this way

```
<script src="http://localhost:8000/build/vendor.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8000/build/main.css" media="screen" />
<script src="http://localhost:8000/build/main.js"></script>
```

And in production html (resides in `/build/`):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" media="screen"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

Configs differ in following:

1. Production env removes
   `react-hot style-loader css-loader less-loader` loaders,
   entries `'webpack/hot/dev-server' 'webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8000'`, `HotModuleReplacementPlugin()`, `#eval` devtool
2. Production env adds:
   `style css less` loaders, `optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin()`, `optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({comments: /a^/, compress: {warnings: false}}`, `sourcemap` devtool

Thanks for help!

Comment: Just checking, but when you invoke webpack at the command line does the build folder actually have a vendor.js mian.js and main.css file in the folder?

Comment: Yes ofc, minified, and the maps also, building goes well. Thanks for concern!

Comment: I have the same problem.  Did you ever figure it out?  I thought we could just upload the build to a static file server and it would work?

Comment: Static server should work.
That time I moved prod folder in root, in config try changing output.path and output.publicPath.